Unable to decrypt public key encrypted string from json body PHP
I was struggling to decrypt a public key encrypted string when sent in a json body encoded using base64.
On the client, I have a string that I encrypt using a public key. Once the string is encrypted, I encode as base64, escape the string, then include as a parameter in a JSON body then send to server via API endpoint POST method. The request looks something like this;
{
    "token":"d154c65681d38db24bffec2c70c034580b8bfadcb62b1952c4bd9f4d88414a02",
    "key":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\nRjt2BQNJVKUqXA\/aoQghnxdCjKT\/ZZUSL2Ll\/kauB+Y3kJCWNL7CfoWI8aPnBu7F\r\nrexvIWnS\/HLNR+uAc5Fs7wir6bT0SY1cF9ZVxzVZlZD16KGX94sxwN=WSpWcemyu4B\r\nWk5348OjME9I23tIwm9tb3BcX33LDr3CJAH5\/lsk5QnT95I6KZNkJzl26XW3+U6u\r\nFhuBPMr\/DrQXcwMHHEt8MswresrxZwSIUTzcQ7xag8n4JGnnoT8nVEuONhIM1\r\ntmF0h6PcmbK3G0zvdcoZw0k74w72\/oVOoHdq3Y+u4clxgFQNY+spQHFI1rE78Ovj\r\n1yAQm5nky9XNrJsy2PpqPg==\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}

When the data is received by the server (PHP), the data is already unescaped so all I should need to do is base64 decode that string, then decrypt using openssl_private_decrypt() and things should be fine but I cannot get the decryption to work. I keep getting an error;
Error decrypting keys error:0200009F:rsa routines::pkcs decoding error 

During troubleshooting, I took the same string and encrypted using the same public key using openssl, and saved it to a file. I then updated the decryption method on the server to read in the saved file instead of using the JSON body field and it works just fine.
Based on my troubleshooting, my issue seems to be that if I base64 encode the encrypted string then try to decode the base64 encoded output of the decrypted string, decryption fails with the rsa decoding error above.
I confirmed this by encrypting the string using openssl, base64 encoding the encrypted output, then updating my PHP code to base64 decode and then attempt to decrypt the decoded data and it fails as well but if I just pass in the encrypted data without encoding, it's fine. I can't seem to figure out what's going on.
I did another test where I converted the encrypted file to hex instead of base64 encoding it, then converting back to bin it and that seems to work OK.
So I guess I have a way of doing this but can anyone tell me why I can't base64 encode the encrypted data for transmission and decrypt properly? Or can I, and I'm just doing something wrong?
Edit: Here is some sample code snippets;
The $cipher is encrypted on the client side, base64 encoded then sent to the server via API endpoint in the JSON body. ie;
{
"keys":<key>
}

To replicate, generate an RSA keypair using openssl;
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout > public.pem 

you can use openssl to encrypt a string using the public key that you can use as the cipher that you will encode to base64;
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -pubin -in string_to_encrypt.txt -out encrypted_string.enc 

        //Read in the encrypted string from file
        $cipherFile = fopen(<path to encrypted_string.enc>,"r");
        $cipherStream = fread($cipherFile,8192);
        $encodedCipher = base64_encode($cipherStream);
        fclose($cipherFile);
        $decodedCipher = base64_decode($cipherStream);
        $privateKeyFile = fopen(<path to private.pem>,"r");
        $privateKeyStream = fread($privateKeyFile,8192);
        fclose($privateKeyFile);
        $pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyStream,<private key passphase>);
        if (!$pkey) {
            Log::error("Error extracting private key");
        }
        //The decryption always fails here
        if (!openssl_private_decrypt($decodedCipher, $decryptedString, $pkey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING)) {
            Log::error("Error decrypting keys " . openssl_error_string());
            return null;
        }

Now, if you change
$encodedCipher = base64_encode($cipherStream);
//and
$decodedCipher = base64_decode($cipherStream);

to
$encodedCipher = bin2hex($cipherStream);
//and
$decodedCipher = hex2bin($cipherStream);

decryption is successful

can you please show us the exact code you're using when you get that errors, and how you pass the data into it. A description is great but we also need a [mre] of the issue to confirm the scenario and work out how to fix it. You can [edit] your post, of course. Thanks

@ADyson ok. I will do that. Thx.
